# Database not updating with PDO statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is there something wrong with the syntax of the statement? I've been messing around with inserting different variables into the code and it still wont update in phpmyadmin. Pretty new with this language so please bear with me.

Pretty sure the line giving me the issue is:

```
$pdoQuery ="UPDATE `Lab4` SET `ActiveUser`=".$Yes." WHERE UserName=".$Email."";
```

I just don't know what the issue is...

```
<?php
   //connect to the database
   session_start(); //this must be the very first line on the php page, to register this page to use session variables
      $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();

   //if this is a page that requires login always perform this session verification
   //require_once "inc/sessionVerify.php"; 

     require_once "dbconnect.php";
     require_once "inc/util2.php";
     require_once "mail/mail.class.php";

      include "header.php";

   // $EmailCode = $_GET["Code"];
     if (isset($_SESSION['Code'])){
     echo $_SESSION['Code'];
     echo $_SESSION['Email'];
     }
     ?>


      <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){

                 try {
                  $pdoConnect = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

              }
              catch (PDOException $exc) {
                  echo $exc->getMessage();
                  exit();
              }
              //$NotAnActiveUserYet = "No";            
             // mysql query to insert data
            $Email = $_SESSION['Email'];
             $Yes = "Yes";  



              $pdoQuery ="UPDATE `Lab4` SET `ActiveUser`=".$Yes." WHERE UserName=".$Email."";
              $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
              $pdoResult->execute(); 
              if ($pdoResult) {
                  echo 'Data Inserted';
              } else {
                  echo 'Data Not Inserted';
              }
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Comment: Short answer: You've completely failed to escape things properly. Use placeholder values and your problem's solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_Try something along these lines:

```
$params = array(
    'ActiveUser' => $Yes,
    'UserName' => $Email,
);

$pdoQuery ='UPDATE `Lab4` SET `ActiveUser`=:ActiveUser WHERE `UserName`=:UserName';
$pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
$pdoResult->execute($params);
```

And as tadman said,... NEVER trust anything from a browser. (includes $_REQUEST, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, etc.)